# Doing owner draw in WPF items generated by data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview, treeviewitem

I am currently working on a WPF TreeView display. The content of this TreeView is from ordinary Data Binding:

```
<TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      x:Name="LogMonitor" 
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntries, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged }">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                DataType="{x:Type Log:SystemLog}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lines}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

The TreeView is filtered by keyword, but I would also like to have keyword highlighting for all the TreeViewItem that remain in the TreeView.

For instance, if there is a TreeViewItem with Header *"This is an apple"* and the user typed *"apple"* as filtering keyword, it should show a TreeViewItem looks like:

[image: Highlight]

I tried some approaches, but there is not much luck.

1. Using built-in styling : 
   The highlighting requires string matching and placing the color block underneath the matched substring. There seems no built-in style template that can be costumed into that way.
2. Draw to canvas in ViewModel object and bind the canvas to the TreeViewItem : 
   It works only when the TreeViewItem is not selected, once selected, the built-in draw call cannot find a way to paint the canvas in the "highlight" style and just leaves a blank area.
3. Create a subclass of TreeViewItem and override OnRender function, then substitute the ItemContainerGenerator of the TreeView to return my subclass of TreeViewItem : 
   Impossible, ItemContainerGenerator of TreeView is not settable and non-virtual.

   And I can only think of one more option :
4. Give up Data Binding, push the subclass of TreeViewItem with overrided OnRender function into Items list of TreeView by myself.

It gives me positive result in the experiment. But I feel uncomfortable about dropping Data Binding paradigm. So I would like to ask is there any other way to do owner draw with Data Binding presents.

Thank you.

Comment: it makes no sense to do `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` into a one way binding S:

Comment: I would use Snoop to examine the visual layers and see if there were an Adorner layer that I could use to add the red rectangle into that was above the treeview, but below the text for the node. I wonder if the TreeView's adorner layer would be the solution

Comment: I found Snoop an amazing tool. Thank you. Though I still haven't find a decent way to do what I want.

On direction I tried is overriding GetContainerForItemOverride of TreeView and return the subclass I want. Then doing OnRender override in the TreeViewItem subclass. It somehow works, bur there are couple glitches I can hardly get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user control that breaks up the text into 3 areas: prehighlight, highlight, and post highlight.  You can do this all with standard binding and styling. Each TreeViewItem would be one of these controls.

Comment: Just for argument sake, what if the keyword is present twice in the same text?

Comment: Good point. We didn't have that scenario when used this method. Another idea to use a StackPanel that you fill with TextBlocks with the appropriate styles. Perhaps fill it on the change of a property.